# Routig problem with storing data from fetch on other page

Tags: flutter

So here is my problem. I have to route to the page EditReservationScrenn from the general ReservationScreen I have, which simply shows a list of all reservations in a ListView.builder. On tab on one of those elements you then get routed(with an argument which is the complete item) to a next screen. On this EditReservationScreen the data of the passed argument gets presented on the screen as ListTiles. So here's the catch... By taping on the Icon which is presented as trailing you then get transferred to yet another screen where you can change your choice.

this all works. BUT. Whenever I tried to Navigator.pop(new argument) back to the EditReservationScreen I'm not able to update the screen with the new value nor to even store it because it is always overwritten.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/models/customer.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/models/performance.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/models/reservation.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/models/seat.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/provider/performance_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/provider/reservation_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/selections/add_performance_selection_screen.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/selections/add_seat_selection_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EditReservationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-reservation';

  @override
  _EditReservationScreenState createState() => _EditReservationScreenState();
}

class _EditReservationScreenState extends State<EditReservationScreen> {
  List<Seat> selectedSeats = [];
  List<Reservation> reservations = [];
  Customer customer;

  var _newPerformance = Performance(
    id: null,
    movie: null,
    dateTime: null,
    theater: null,
  );

  var _newReservation = Reservation(
    id: null,
    seat: null,
    customer: null,
    performance: null,
  );

  /* Future<void> _getPerformance() async {
    final pId = await Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamed(AddPerformanceSelectionScreen.routeName);

    Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetPerformances();
    var performance =
        Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false).findById(pId);

    setState(() {
      _newPerformance = Performance(
        id: pId,
        dateTime: performance.dateTime,
        movie: performance.movie,
        theater: performance.theater,
      );

      _newReservation = Reservation(
        id: _newReservation.id,
        seat: null,
        customer: _newReservation.customer,
        performance: performance,
      );
    });
  } */

  Future<void> _getReservation() async {
    final reservation = /* final reservationId = */
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Reservation;
    Performance performance = reservation.performance;
    _newReservation = Reservation(
      customer: reservation.customer,
      id: reservation.id,
      performance: reservation.performance,
      seat: reservation.seat,
    );

    customer = reservation.customer;

    _newPerformance = Performance(
      id: performance.id,
      dateTime: performance.dateTime,
      movie: performance.movie,
      theater: performance.theater,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _updateSeat(String id) async {
    Map result = (await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        AddSeatSelectionScreen.routeName,
        arguments: {'id': id, 'customer': _newReservation.customer}) as Map);
    selectedSeats = List<Seat>.from((result['seats'] as List));
    Performance p = result['performance'];
    setState(() {
      _newPerformance = Performance(
        id: p.id,
        dateTime: p.dateTime,
        movie: p.movie,
        theater: p.theater,
      );
      _newReservation = Reservation(
        id: _newReservation.id,
        seat: selectedSeats,
        customer: _newReservation.customer,
        performance: _newReservation.performance,
      );
    });
  }

  void _updateReservation() {
    setState(() {
      _newReservation = Reservation(
        id: _newReservation.id,
        seat: _newReservation.seat,
        customer: _newReservation.customer,
        performance: _newReservation.performance,
      );
    });
    reservations.add(_newReservation);

    _newPerformance = Performance(
      id: _newPerformance.id,
      dateTime: _newPerformance.dateTime,
      movie: _newPerformance.movie,
      theater: _newPerformance.theater,
    );
    Provider.of<ReservationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .addReservation(_newReservation);
    Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .updatePerformance(_newPerformance.id, _newPerformance);
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  String setSeatNumbers() {
    List<int> seatNumbers = [];
    List<Seat> seats = List<Seat>.from(_newReservation.seat);
    String seatNumbersToString = '';
    seats.forEach((seat) {
      seatNumbers.add(seat.seatNumber);
    });
    seatNumbers.forEach((s) {
      seatNumbersToString = '$seatNumbersToString, $s';
    });
    seatNumbersToString = seatNumbersToString.substring(1);
    return seatNumbersToString;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final reservation =
        ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Reservation;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Reservation bearbeiten'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: _updateReservation),
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getReservation(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => buildList(/* reservation */),
        ));
  }

  Widget buildList(/* Reservation reservation */) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              child: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
            title: Text(
                '${_newReservation.customer.firstName} ${_newReservation.customer.lastName}'),
            subtitle: Text('${_newReservation.customer.phoneNumber}'),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              child: Icon(Icons.movie),
            ),
            title: Text(
              '${_newReservation.performance.movie.title}',
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
                '${DateFormat.d().add_MMMM().add_y().format(_newReservation.performance.dateTime)} um ${DateFormat().add_Hm().format(_newReservation.performance.dateTime)}'),
            trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () async {
                  final pId = await Navigator.of(context)
                      .pushNamed(AddPerformanceSelectionScreen.routeName);
                  print(pId);
                  Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .fetchAndSetPerformances();
                  var performance =
                      Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false)
                          .findById(pId);
                  setState(() {
                    _newPerformance = Performance(
                      id: pId,
                      dateTime: performance.dateTime,
                      movie: performance.movie,
                      theater: performance.theater,
                    );
                    _newReservation = Reservation(
                      id: _newReservation.id,
                      seat: null,
                      customer: _newReservation.customer,
                      performance: performance,
                    );
                  });
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.event_seat,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
            title: _newReservation.seat == null
                ? Text('Sitze wählen')
                : Text('Sitze: ${setSeatNumbers()}'),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () => _updateSeat(_newReservation.performance.id),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/provider/reservation_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/screens/reservation_screens/add_reservation_screen.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/screens/reservation_screens/search_reservation_screen.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/widgets/reservation_item.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ReservationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/reservation';

  Future<void> _refreshReservations(BuildContext context) async {
    await Provider.of<ReservationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetReservations();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Reservationen'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () =>
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AddReservationScreen.routeName),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: Text('Reservation suchen'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SearchReservationScreen.routeName),
        icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _refreshReservations(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState ==
                ConnectionState.waiting
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : RefreshIndicator(
                onRefresh: () => _refreshReservations(context),
                child: Consumer<ReservationProvider>(
                  builder: (context, reservation, _) => Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ReservationItem(
                            id: reservation.reservation[index].id,
                            customer: reservation.reservation[index].customer,
                            dateTime: reservation
                                .reservation[index].performance.dateTime,
                            movieName: reservation
                                .reservation[index].performance.movie.title,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      itemCount: reservation.reservation.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/provider/movie_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/provider/performance_provider.dart';
import 'package:kinobuchungssystem/src/widgets/select_performance.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AddPerformanceSelectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/select-performance';

  Future<void> _setPerformace(BuildContext context) async {
    await Provider.of<PerformanceProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetPerformances();
    await Provider.of<MovieProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAndSetMovies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Vorstellung auswählen'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _setPerformace(context),
        builder: (context, snapshot) =>
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: () => _setPerformace(context),
                    child: Consumer2<PerformanceProvider, MovieProvider>(
                      builder: (context, performance, movie, _) => Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: performance.performance.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final loadedMovie = movie.findById(performance.performance[index].movie.id);
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  SelectPerformance(
                                      id: performance.performance[index].id,
                                      movieName: loadedMovie.title,
                                      dateTime: performance.performance[index].dateTime),
                                  Divider(),
                                ],
                              );
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class SelectPerformance extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String movieName;
  final DateTime dateTime;

  SelectPerformance({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.movieName,
    @required this.dateTime,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final time = DateFormat.Hm().format(dateTime);
    final date = DateFormat.d().add_MMMM().add_y().format(dateTime);
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, id),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            print(id);
            Navigator.pop(context, id);
          },
          color: Colors.amberAccent,
        ),
        title: Text('$movieName'),
        subtitle: Text(date),
        trailing: CircleAvatar(
          child: Text(time),
          radius: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I suppose it reloads because of the ModalRout.of. Or of the FutureBuilder... But I found no way to fix it.

Comment: did you get the new id back after the navigatio.pop pId? do you find the pid in the provider PerformanceProvider?

Comment: what does the futurBuilder? or where comes the initial from _newReservation? please more code

Comment: yes I get the new Id back I just can't update the actual reservation with the new value.

Comment: As for the futureBuilder i used it to fetch the data when I was running the code the first time

Answer (score 0):

every `setState` in the class EditReservationScreen() also the `FuturBuilder` is calling `_getReservation()`
and the `_newPerformance` is updating again with old values

call _getReservation only one time in the initstate, without any futureBuilder

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getReservation();
  }
```

Or you save your updates in the Provider before you call `setstate` in `_updateSeat()`